# Javascript referencing to id element in php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've got a form that displays user data in php.  Then I've got an input field where the qty should be inputted.  Then the JS that executes calculates the total and updates the total input element.

The problem is the referencing to the relevant id element of the input.  The JS I have is only referencing to the last element in the php array.  So eg the id name is `id="qty" . $userid`, so for example the id name will be qtyuser001, qtyuser002, qtyuser003, etc, but JS only refers to qtyuser003.

I've been struggling with this for more than a day trying different methods, I can't get it to work.  Is there an alternative method I should be approaching to solve this problem?

**The php code**

```
$get2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...");

echo '<form method="post" action="">';
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get2)) {

$userID = $row2['userID'];
$fn = $row2['FirstName'];
$ln = $row2['LastName'];

echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input readonly name="userID[]" id="userID ' . $userID . '" value="' . $userID . '"></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $fn . ' ' .  $ln . '</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" size="5" name="nrOfQ[]" id="nrOfQ' . $userID . '" onchange="calc()"></td>';
    echo '<td><input readonly type="text" size="5" name="total" id="total' . $userID . '"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

**The JS code**

```
<script>
function calc() {
    var userid = <?php echo json_encode($userID); ?>;
    var myrate = <?php echo json_encode($FieldInterviewerRate); ?>;
    var myqty = document.getElementById('nrOfQ' + userid).value; 
    myResult = myqty * myrate;
    var elem = document.getElementById('total' + userid);
    elem.value = myResult;
}
</script>
```

*I don't now Javascript that well*

Comment: What errors you are getting in `console`?

Comment: PHP is server side. JS is client side. So they are completely independent. You probably have problems with JS and HTML, not with JS and PHP.

Comment: I don't get any errors, it is only doing the calculation on the last array, for example if in JS I add alert(userid) it is only returning the last row in the php array

Comment: Yes probably with JS & HTML, sorry

Comment: First, install jQuery

Comment: I think the real problem is you use variable $userID in you JS-code after init in in while and set last value for this variable. Don't use php variable in JS, use JS in JS, navigate by DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem that you are not init the JS function each time and you shouldt. The JS code shouldn't depend of PHP and mast be dynamic.
Please Try this

php

```
$get2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...");

    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get2)) {

    $userID = $row2['userID'];
    $fn = $row2['FirstName'];
    $ln = $row2['LastName'];

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input readonly name="userID[]" id="userID ' . $userID . '" value="' . $userID . '">
        <input type="hidden" id="myRate' . $userID . '"></td>';

        echo '<td>' . $fn . ' ' .  $ln . '</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" size="5" name="nrOfQ[]" id="nrOfQ' . $userID . '" onchange="calc(this)"></td>';
        echo '<td><input readonly type="text" size="5" name="total" id="total' . $userID . '"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';


    <script>
function calc(obj) {


    var id = obj.id;
    var userId = id.substr(5);

    var myrate = document.getElementById('myRate' + userId).value; 
    var myqty = document.getElementById('nrOfQ' + userId).value; 
    myResult = myqty * myrate;
    var elem = document.getElementById('total' + userId);
    elem.value = myResult;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok I am testing and will give feedback soon :)

Comment: some change in a js part

Comment: Thank you volkinc, really apreciate it